# R - Check if element from vector exist in data.frame, and if not, add dummy values

Tags: r, if-statement, vector, rbind

Having a vector of campaigns:

```
campaignsTypes <- c("Social Media","Distribution","Nurture","Newsletter","Push")
```

and a data.frame with information about them:

```
out <- structure(list(Type = c("Distribution", "Newsletter", "Nurture", 
"Social Media"), Pageviews = c(42, 880, 17, 84)), .Names = c("Type", 
"Pageviews"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to check if all elements from vector `campaignsTypes` are included in the data.frame `out`, and if not, create a new row with dummy values for this missing campaign. So far, I can check if a campaigngType is not present. However, I'm having problems into assigning the not existing element from vector as value for the first column of a manually inserted new row:

```
> ifelse(campaignsTypes %in% out$Type == FALSE,rbind(out, c(????,0)),"")
How to put the value of the missing campaign here?----------⤴
```

Comment: What is your expected output?  Do you need `campaignsTypes$ind <- if(all(campaignsTypes %in% out$Type)) 1 else 0`

Comment: @akrun, the expected output should be a data.frame like `output <- structure(list(Type = c("Distribution", "Newsletter", "Nurture", "Social Media", "Push"), Pageviews = c(42, 880, 17, 84,0)), .Names = c("Type", "Pageviews"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")`, where output$Type should include all elements of vector `campaignsType`. If the Type has been included as a result of that the statement campaignsTypes %in% out$Type == FALSE is true, output$Pageviews for this observation will be assigned with a 0

Comment: I have edited the question to delete the first ifelse statement, as it creates confusions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new data frame with the missing rows, and then stack the
two data frames.

```
rbind(out, data.frame(Type=setdiff(campaignsTypes, out$Type),
                      Pageviews=0L))
```

Result:

```
          Type Pageviews
1 Distribution        42
2   Newsletter       880
3      Nurture        17
4 Social Media        84
5         Push         0
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it,

```
output <- rbind(out, campaignsTypes[sapply(campaignsTypes, function(i) !(i %in% out$Type))])
output$Pageviews[output$Pageviews == output$Type] <- 0
output
#          Type Pageviews
#1 Distribution        42
#2   Newsletter       880
#3      Nurture        17
#4 Social Media        84
#5         Push         0
```

Comment: This solution works perfect. However, I have chosen Ernest A solution as answer, only because the process is done in just one step.

Comment: That's fine. It's a better answer anyway. I totally forgot about `setdiff` hence I used a loop...